# How to verify that this Windows system trusts a given SSL server certificate?

Tags: .net, windows, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm in .NET (actually, C#) code on a Windows system, and I'm given (the thumbprint or entire public part of) an SSL server certificate S.  Now I'd like to know (in .NET code):

> Would .NET code running on this system trust this server certificate X?

E.g., if on this system I would create a [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and point it to an HTTPS URL which uses that server certificate, would it then be trusted?

I know I can look in to the Windows trust store (Local Computer -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities etc.) and try to compute whether X is trusted, also looking at intermediate authorities, the certificate chain, etc..  But I have no idea what algorithm to implement exactly, so I'd very much prefer to reuse the algorithm that .NET already uses.

(To clarify, this is in an installer-type program, where a server using certificate X is not actually yet available-- otherwise I could just do a test call to such a server, and see whether or not a trust error results.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have whole SSL certificate or only its thumbprint/public key?

To check trust of one certificate you need to build whole chain to the root CA and this root CA needs to be in trusted root store (LocalMachine or CurrentUser). But without the SSL certificate as x509 or without knowledge about its issuer it will not be possible.

If you have SSL certificate you can build the chain using [X509Chain class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its [Build method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.build%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then check the ChainStatus to get detailed error information for the status of the chain.

Comment: +1 We have the entire certificate, and the Build() methods works fine for us.  Thanks!